# Rally SDK 2.0 Display User Story Parent (Feature) and Sort by Parent in rallygrid

Tags: rally, appsdk2

Having trouble showing parent feature of user stories and sorting by that same parent field.  Here's my code.  I see empty value in Parent column unless the parent is another user story.  And I am not able to sort by Parent field.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        itemId: 'iterationFilter'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        itemId: 'grid',
                        width: 800
                    }
                ],

                launch: function() {
                    this.down('#iterationFilter').add({
                        xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
                        cls: 'filter',
                        model: 'UserStory',
                        field: 'Iteration',
                        listeners: {
                            ready: this._onIterationComboBoxLoad,
                            select: this._onIterationComboBoxSelect,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });
                },

                _onIterationComboBoxLoad: function(comboBox) {
                    this.iterationComboBox = comboBox;

                    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                        type: 'UserStory',
                        success: this._onModelRetrieved,
                        scope: this
                    });
                },                  

                _getFilter: function() {
                    var filter = [];

                    filter.push({
                        property: 'Iteration',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: this.iterationComboBox.getValue()
                    });

                    return filter;
                },


                _onIterationComboBoxSelect: function() {
                    this._onSettingsChange();
                },

                _onSettingsChange: function() {
                    this.grid.filter(this._getFilter(), true, true);
                },

                _onModelRetrieved: function(model) {
                    this.grid = this.down('#grid').add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        model: model,
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'Plan Estimate',
                            'Parent',
                            'Schedule State',
                            'StoryType'
                        ],
                        storeConfig: {
                            context: this.context.getDataContext(),
                            filters: this._getFilter()
                        },
                        showPagingToolbar: true,
                        enableEditing: false
                    });
                }



            });
        });


      Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
          name: 'Defect Dashboard'
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

User Stories have two different fields for their Parent. If the Parent is another story it uses Parent. In the case where the Parent is a Portfolio Item like a Feature the parent will be called PortfolioItem.

You can see the fields on user story by looking at our webservice [docs](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#HierarchicalRequirement).

In your example you would have to change your column configs to include PorfolioItem

```
columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'Plan Estimate',
                            'PortfolioItem',
                            'Schedule State',
                            'StoryType'
                        ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But it still does not work.
I noticed that I should also change 'Plan Estimate' -> 'PlanEstimate' and 'ScheduleState' -> 'ScheduleState'.  

However, 'PortfolioItem' does not show up in my grid still.

    columnCfgs: [
     'FormattedID',
     'Name',
     'PlanEstimate',
     'PortfolioItem',
     'ScheduleState',
     'StoryType'
    ]

Comment: Actually, any field with "Sortable = False" cannot be displayed in this grid.  Tested with a couple of other fields.  And 'PortfolioItem' is NOT sortable.  Does this mean that there's no way to show a list of user stories sorted by PortfolioItem/Feature?

Comment: Looks like I have to add a renderer to extract out the name of portolioitem for display.

Answer (score 0):

I was at least able to show the name of feature for each user story.  I am still having an issue to make it sortable though.  :(

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Grid Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p4/sdk.js?wsapiVersion=1.38"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                Rally.onReady(function() {
                    Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                        extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                        componentCls: 'app',

                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                itemId: 'iterationFilter'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                itemId: 'grid'
                                //width: 800
                            }
                        ],

                        launch: function() {
                            this.down('#iterationFilter').add({
                                xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
                                cls: 'filter',
                                model: 'UserStory',
                                field: 'Iteration',
                                listeners: {
                                    ready: this._onIterationComboBoxLoad,
                                    select: this._onIterationComboBoxSelect,
                                    scope: this
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        _onIterationComboBoxLoad: function(comboBox) {
                            this.iterationComboBox = comboBox;

                            Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                                type: 'UserStory',
                                success: this._onModelRetrieved,
                                scope: this
                            });
                        },                  

                        _getFilter: function() {
                            var filter = [];

                            filter.push({
                                property: 'Iteration',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: this.iterationComboBox.getValue()
                            });

                            return filter;
                        },


                        _onIterationComboBoxSelect: function() {
                            this._onSettingsChange();
                        },

                        _onSettingsChange: function() {
                            this.grid.filter(this._getFilter(), true, true);
                        },

                        _onModelRetrieved: function(model) {
                            this.grid = this.down('#grid').add({
                                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                                model: model,
                                columnCfgs: [
                                    'FormattedID',
                                    'Name',
                                    'PlanEstimate',
                                    {
                                        text: 'Feature',
                                        dataIndex: 'PortfolioItem',
                                        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
                                            if (value != null) {
                                                return value.Name;
                                            }
                                            return '';
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'ScheduleState',
                                    'StoryType'
                                ],
                                storeConfig: {
                                    context: this.context.getDataContext(),
                                    remoteSort: false,
                                    filters: this._getFilter()
                                },
                                showPagingToolbar: true,
                                enableEditing: false
                            });
                        }



                    });
                });


              Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                  name: 'Defect Dashboard'
              });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .filter {
                float: left;
                margin: 5px 5px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your revised solution with the renderer, all you need to add is a doSort method to the custom column you have set up.  Make sure you set remoteSort to false on the store, then you can override the sorting with a method:

```
        doSort: function(state) {
            var ds = this.up('grid').getStore();
            var field = this.getSortParam();
            ds.sort({
                property: field,
                direction: state,
                sorterFn: function(v1, v2){
                    v1 = v1.get(field);
                    v2 = v2.get(field);
                    return v1.length > v2.length ? 1 : (v1.length < v2.length ? -1 : 0);
                }
            });
        }
```

This sorter happens to sort by the length of the the field, but you can change it to do what you want. See [Ext js sorting custom column by contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795019/ext-js-sorting-custom-column-by-contents)