# ExtJS 5.0 - override to provide custom ordering on a grid column

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

A grid control column is ordering based on `name` which is a combined field of `first + ' ' + last`. The client wants to order by `last + ', ' + first`. I am not permitted to change the existing code, can only use overrides.

Based on the results of web searching, I think using `sortType` to transform the input value is the least intrusive approach. But I'm not sure how to plug it in.

I think `sortType` works on data fields, so in an `initComponent` overload can I get access to what I need? For example, this is how I override in the view to change the rendering:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent([]);
    this.columns[0].renderer =
        function(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
            var result = '';
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(record.data) && !Ext.isEmpty(record.data.details)) {
                var details = record.data.details;
                // value == details.name is 'first last', won't be using that
                result = details.last + ', ' + details.first;
            }
            return result;
        };
}
```

Can I get access to the `details.name` definition from here to override `sortType`? Will agree that this *isn't* the best approach, because I'll have to do some parsing of `name` to split it and then stick it back together. And that's going to have issues for those with multiple first and/or last names.

An alternate approach is to overload `doSort` but if I don't have access to `details.first` and `details.last`, it won't be any better than `sortType`. I saw one example of implementing `doSort` and it looks very complicated. Does anyone know of some detailed documentation for `doSort`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sortType does not take the whole record, and it is applied directly to `columns[0].dataIndex`, without any possibility to interfere. And you can only use string manipulation if you are sure where first name ends and last name starts:

```
this.columns[0].sortType = function(value) {
    var spl = value.split(' ');
    return value[1] + ', ' + value[0];
}
```

Of course this will run into issues with Names like "Carl Friedrich Theodor Wilhelm Freiherr von und zu Guttenberg" and the like, even "George W. Bush" would be an issue.

The better way is to introduce another field into the model, something along the lines of

```
MyApp.model.Resource.getFields().push(Ext.create('Ext.data.Field',{
    name:"LastFirst",
    convert:function(v,rec) {
        return rec.get("last")+', '+rec.get("first")
    }
}));
```

This change does not affect existing model instances, so you would have to do it before any model instance is created.

This would allow you to set `columns[0].dataIndex="LastFirst"`, scrap the renderer change, and also get useful sorting.

Comment: Thank you. I put the code in the store constructor override: `var fields = this.model.getFields();`, then iterated through `fields` to check if the field was not present.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give some code or a stub, but i found some answers about ordering. As i know ext 4 have sortType on a stores. So what you actually need is to create custom sortType to your store (and to create a store if you haven`t it yet).
Ext have ways to order things in a grid, use initComponent for other stuff.
sortType looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198722/extjs-5-how-to-sort-grid-column-in-ext-js-5)